# regex code preg_split (:)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

For the following code:

```
$string = "hello: Mister, Winterbottom";

$words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);
print_r ($words);
```

I get:

```
Array ( [0] => hello: [1] => Mister [2] => Winterbottom )
```

but I want the results to be:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => Mister [2] => Winterbottom )
```

so that it will ignore the colon. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `/[\s,:]+/`. Or `/\W+/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to expand your character class with `:`, just put it inside it and use

```
/[\s,:]+/
```

See [its demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uwfQoD/1). Or, just use [`/\W+/`](https://regex101.com/r/uwfQoD/2) to split with 1+ non-word characters.

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s,:]+/", $string);
print_r ($words);
// Or
print_r(preg_split("/\W+/", $string));
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/dXZ1y0)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "hello: Mister, Winterbottom";

$words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);

$words[0] = rtrim($words[0],":");

print_r ($words);
```

Comment: Answers should have an explanation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.